# New line upon return key in UITextView

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi How do I set return key to a new line to UITextView below? Thanks

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
if (range.length == 0) {
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        return NO;
    }
}

return YES;

}
```

Comment: wt u want Exatly ?? i cnt understand :(

Comment: UITextView is set to editable and when typing in this, I need the return key to create a new line in the multiline UITextView

Comment: u want ..when u tapped on return key then new line created in UItextView ??

Comment: it is default behavior of UITextView..when u click on return key then it add next line in UITExtView..

Comment: I have updated the code above, it seems something is interfering with next line for UIReturnKeyDefault, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can make done button on navigation bar to hide keyBoard.

Because next button on keyBoard in `UITextView` will give you new line.

**EDIT**

Remove this line from your code, it will resigning your keyboard when you are pressing next button

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: UIReturnKeyNext is not for a new line..its for the next field

Comment: UITextView is set to editable and when typing in this, I need the return key to create a new line in the multiline UITextView

Comment: by default return key will create new line in UITextView.

Comment: @user2028990- then u have textField not textView ...checke it ...:)

Comment: mmm for code above it simply isn't doing that. Above Contains (UITextView *)textView

Comment: [textView resignFirstResponder]; this line hiding your keyboard